# Showing multiple records under one record?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have records in my db as below

```
userid    email    first_name    SUM    Currency_flag
1     abc@gmail.com    User2    8609.00    0   
1     abc@gmail.com    User2      12.00    1
9     xyz@gmail.com    User1      99.00    0
9     xyz@gmail.com    User1     200.00    1
34    qwer@gmail.com   User3     345.00    0
34    qwer@gmail.com   User3     200.00    1
12    dfg@gmail.com    User4       0.00    0
12    dfg@gmail.com    User4     280.00    1
```

Now I want to display them as below

```
userid   email    first_name      SUM_0     SUM_1
1     abc@gmail.com    User2    8609.00     12.00
9     xyz@gmail.com    User1      99.00    200.00    
34    qwer@gmail.com   User3     345.00    200.00
12    dfg@gmail.com    User4       0.00    280.00
```

where `sum_0` is SUM value when `currency_flag=0` and `SUM_1` is SUM value when `currency_flag=1`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT 
`userid`, `email`, `first_name`, 
SUM(IF(`currency_flag`=0, `SUM`, 0)) AS `SUM_0` 
SUM(IF(`currency_flag`=1, `SUM`, 0)) AS `SUM_1` 
FROM `users` 
GROUP BY (`userid`)
```

Comment: the condition is some users are having two records with curency flag as 1 and currency flag 0 i wat to dsisplay

Comment: sum of one record with currency flag with 1 in column and sum of one record with currency flag with 0 in another column

Comment: exactly! if you see results array, you fin in $results['SUM_0'] the sum with currency_falg 0, and in $results['SUM_1'] the sum with currency_falg 1!

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this is a self-join:

```
SELECT A.UserID, A.Email, A.First_Name, A.SUM AS SUM_0, B.SUM AS SUM_1
  FROM (SELECT *           FROM AnonymousTable WHERE Currency_Flag = 0) AS A
  JOIN (SELECT UserID, SUM FROM AnonymousTable WHERE Currency_Flag = 1) AS B
    ON A.UserID = B.UserID;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select userid,email,first_name,sum(if(currency_flag=0,SUM,0)),sum(if(currency_flag=1,SUM,0)) 
from table 
group by 1
```

Comment: no i dont want sum .I want SUM value in one column if currency_flag is 0 and sum value in another column in another column if currency_flag=1

Comment: it will be the same as you sum over one element if i'm correct